Shift by month shifts to wrong date
Can someone explain this result to me?
d = [
  {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2013-11-30'), 'metric': 2},
  {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2013-12-01'), 'metric': 0},
  {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2013-12-02'), 'metric': 0},
  {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2013-12-03'), 'metric': 0},
  {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2013-12-04'), 'metric': 0},
  {'Date Enrolled': pd.Timestamp('2013-12-05'), 'metric': 0}
]
tdf = pd.DataFrame(d)
tdf = tdf.set_index(['Date Enrolled']).asfreq('D')
tdf['metric'].shift(periods=1, freq='ME')

result:
Date Enrolled
2013-12-31    2
2013-12-31    0
2013-12-31    0
2013-12-31    0
2013-12-31    0
2013-12-31    0
Name: metric, dtype: int64

expected:
Date Enrolled
2013-12-31    2
2014-01-31    0
2014-01-31    0
2014-01-31    0
2014-01-31    0
2014-01-31    0
Name: metric, dtype: int64


plz explain your logic to get expected output.

@PandaKim - every index value should be set to the last day of the next month.

Naturally, we need to explain by what logic each row gets its value.

@PandaKim - I edited based on some tests and realized I had a mistake.  The metric value doesn't change at all, but all the dates go to 2024-12-31.  Its so confusing.

Code
This is because it goes to the closest of the last days of the month that exist after that date. One way to achieve your result is to use the period data type as shown below.
# your code
tdf = tdf.set_index(['Date Enrolled']).asfreq('D')

# answer
tdf.index = (tdf.index.to_period('M') + 1).to_timestamp('M')

tdf
                metric
Date Enrolled   
2013-12-31      2
2014-01-31      0
2014-01-31      0
2014-01-31      0
2014-01-31      0
2014-01-31      0

